# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] on attempting to load a pdf print page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I have this page that I am tryring to create a demo page to download pdf as seen in this resource. https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

I have created this page but when I run my code I get uncaught injector module error

here is the snippet

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<title>welcome to pdf</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">
<p ng-click="HTMLclick()">click here</p>
<p id="pdfContent">
print here 
</p>

</body>

</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/jspdf@latest/dist/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module('app' ) ;
app.controller('MyController' , function($scope) {

 $scope.HTMLclick = function () {
                var pdf = new jsPDF();
                pdf.addHTML(($("#pdfContent")[0]), { pagesplit: true }, function () {
                    pdf.save('myfilename' + '.pdf');
                });

            };

});

</script>
```

please what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing brackets [] in your module declaration;

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```